# Squares with supremum metric?

Tags: geometry, metric-spaces

Open balls with the sup metric are actually squares? Why?

The sup metric is $$d_s(x,y) = \sup \{ |x_i - y_i | \}$$
and the open ball with sup metric is
$$B_r(x) = \{x : d_s(x,y) < r \}$$

If it was a square, how can it include points on the vertex? Since those points are at distance $\sqrt{2}r$ away

> To make this more concrete, suppose we are on $\mathbb{R}^2$
>
> $$d_s(x,y) = \sup \{ |x_1 - x_1|, |y_1 - y_2| \}$$
>
> Then the open ball with $d_s$ as metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$ is
>
> $$B_1(0,0) =\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : \sup\{ |x_2| , |y_2|\} < 1\} $$
>
> WLOG, we assume $|x_2| > |y_2|$. Then we have
>
> $$B_1(0,0) =\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : |x_2| < 1\} $$
>
> But this actually gives us an infinite rectangle??

Comment: But the *entire point* is that the metric measures distances differently than your usual Euclidean metrix. With the sup metric, the distance from the origin to a corner of the unit ball is 1, by definition.

Comment: Okay, but I am still seeing a circle rather than a square

Answer (score 1):

How do you say "WLOG assume $|x_2| > |y_2|$"?

You are looking at all points $(x,y)$ such that $\sup\{|x|, |y|\} < 1$. ie.
$$
|x| < 1 \text{ and } |y| < 1
$$
$$
\Leftrightarrow -1 < x < 1, \text{ and } -1 < y < 1
$$
Hence,
$$
B_1(0,0) = (-1,1)\times (-1,1)
$$
which is the interior of a square.

Comment: But there can only be one maximum of $|x|$ and $|y|$, so it only one of those, not both.